# Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a non euclidian metric a Riemann surface?

Tags: manifolds, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

Provided that a metric g is regular enough (e.g Chern's condition), one can add a conformal structure to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with metric g to make it a Riemann surface (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510127/when-is-a-riemannian-manifold-a-riemann-surface)).

But **I don't understand in the first place** why can't we directly state that  $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a Riemann surface since the identity atlas with one chart $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is holomorphic (since it has just one chart), independently of g?

**Why do we care so much about the metric g** (we need to stitch together many isothermal local charts instead), since it doesn't change the topology? In the definition of a Riemann surface we need *changes of charts* to be holomorphic, and (topological) homeomorphism between $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}^2$. (Im seeing $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a manifold only with no vector structure/a vector structure induced by its charts). What is mixing me up? Thanks!